# SonarQube rule c:S905 void cast violation

Tags: c, sonarqube

We are using the sonarqube C plugin and have some problems with rule c:S905. The rule make sense and we want to keep it as a critical issue. But we get a lot of violations of this rule when void casting unused parameters in functions, for example in a callback or third party api:s. 
Example:

```
void handleRequest( Address          sender,
                    Msg               * request)
{
    (void)sender; // Not used in function, but wanted in api. Cast to avoid compiler warning

    ... //Do something
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to solve this in a good way?

Comment: I wonder where this tool gets its rules from. Seems like some home-brewed coding standard. I don't see why casting to `(void)` would ever be dangerous or harmful. Do they give a rationale for it?

Comment: Consider for example `(void) func();` versus `func()`. The former means "yes I know that the function returns a value but I have chosen to ignore it". While the latter means "either I don't know that the function returns a value, or I have just forgotten to check it, or possibly I'm just ignoring it". The former is good and safe, self-documenting code. The latter is bad practice and a potential bug.

Comment: @Lundin MISRA has the same rule.

Comment: @2501 No, MISRA-C has an explicit exception for such cases. See MISRA-C:2012 2.2 regarding dead code: "Exception. A cast to void is assumed to indicate a value that is intentionally not being used. The cast is therefore not dead code itself. It is treated as using its operand which is therefore also not dead code.".

Comment: @Lundin  I was using the 2004 version. Can you check if 2012 has the same rule: *Rule 14.2 (required):  All non-null statements shall either:
have at least one side-effect however executed, or (a)
cause control flow to change.* ?

Comment: @2501 As far as I can tell, 2012 2.2 replaces 2004 14.2. The document now speaks of both "unreachable code" (rule 2.1, code which is never executed) and "dead code" (rule 2.2, null statements, statements with no side-effects etc).

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. It seems sonarqube is using 2004 then.

Comment: @2501 It is not really clear if this was a MISRA 2004 violation. I have a faint memory of someone bringing up the case of void casts with the committee. The quoted exception was not part of the 2012 draft, so maybe this was added during the 2012 review.